# *** Assertion failure in -[UIView _addConstraint:],

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am getting below error when I try to add constraint to view.

`*** Assertion failure in -[UIView _addConstraint:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:518`

**code**

```
[self.tabBar removeConstraint:self.bottomSpace];
[self.view removeConstraint:self.bottomSpace];
self.bottomSpaceForTabBar.constant = ...;
[self.view addConstraint:self.bottomSpace];
```

`self.bottomSpace` is added in IB and I have IBOutlet it.

Comment: what is `self.bottomSpace` is it different to `self.bottomSpaceForTabBar`?

Comment: @L14M333 Sorry it was a mistake. Changed it.

Comment: Why do your first 2 lines remove the same constraint twice, from different views? You should only need one of those.

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay Because sometimes I see that if I do `_autolayoutTrace` on views then the constraint is added into both of them.

Comment: You should remove a constraint from the view you added it to. Also, but you shouldn't have to remove/re-add any constraints just to change a constant.

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay I added it in IB, not in code. So how do I know that constraint was added in which view? Doing `_autolayoutTrace` on views shows that it is added in both of the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing lines that removes and adds constraint. And keeping only

```
self.bottomSpaceForTabBar.constant = ...;
```

I don't know why this solved. I would like to listen from others on this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I was missing.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

In the parent view controller.